# How do I make a diagonal strikethrough on wordpress?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

I'm trying to achieve the look for a discounted product and I want a diagonal strikethrough on the old price. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! notice that your question has nothing to do with wordpress, its only CSS and targeting the correct elements to apply that css to. In the future, if you have a question that doesn't envolve WordPress, you better ask it on stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

The html structure for WooCommerce original price, if sale price exists is this.

```html
<del>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>49.90
        </bdi>
    </span>
</del>
```

Now if I paste this code below without the code formatter

<del>₪49.90</del>

You can see that the price already has a line through.

Do you want to add a different design or does your `<del>` price doesn't have a line  through?

If you have thos exact html structure and you are missing the line through you can add it in the css, like this.

```css
.woocommerce .price del {
    text-decoration: line-through; /* add !important if its still not showong */
}
```

If you would like to add diagonal line you could do something like this

```css
.woocommerce .price del {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.woocommerce .price del:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-15deg);
}
```